# Easy way to excecute method after a given delay?

Tags: windows-phone-7, timer, thread-safety, backgroundworker

Is there a easy way to perform a method after a given delay like in iOS out of the box?

On iPhone I would do this:

`[self performSelector:@selector(connectSensor) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];`

It will then schedule the method `connectSensor` on the main thread (UI thread) to be executed after 2,5 seconds. And because it is automatically scheduled on the main thread, you don't have to worry about cross thread issues. (There is also a `performSelectorOnBackground` version)

**So how would I do this properly in WP7?**

Currently I'm accomplishing this with a timer, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution.

```
    private Timer timer;
    private void DoSomethingAfterDaly()
    {
        // ... do something here

        timer = new Timer( (o) => Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.GoBack()), null, 2500, Timeout.Infinite);            
    }
```

How could this be encapsulated into an extension method so I can just call `this.Perform(MyMethod, null, 2500);` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a BackgroundWorker like so:

```
    private void Perform(Action myMethod, int delayInMilliseconds)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (s, e) => Thread.Sleep(delayInMilliseconds);

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => myMethod.Invoke();

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

The call into this method would look like this:

```
this.Perform(() => MyMethod(), 2500);
```

The background worker will run the sleep on a thread off of the UI thread so your application is free to do other things while the delay is occurring.

Comment: Why is this better then using a Timer?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Reactive Extensions for WP7 to observe on a timer:

```
Observable
  .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500))
  .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
  .Subscribe(_ =>
    {
      NavigationService.GoBack();
    });
```

Given the brevity of this code, I don't think you'd gain much by creating an extension method for it :) For more information about the Reactive Extensions for WP7, take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431792(v=VS.92).aspx)
.

Comment: But then I have to unsubscribe it again and that's not really what I want. I want a elegant (more or less) one liner to execute a method after a delay.

Comment: According to the documentation, SubscribeOnDispatcher subscribes *and unsubscribes* observers using the current dispatcher.

Comment: thx didn't read that unsubscribe part. Just tried it out, but SubscribeOnDispatcher does not take any parameters. So your posted code does not compile. Does it miss a `SubscribeOnDispatcher().Do((o) => ... );` ? Evenso if I do this, the code in Do() is not executed at all.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. Confusingly, there shoudl be an extra Subscribe; I've updated the code in my original answer.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing so this has me excited. However, I get `Error 1 'Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.Observable.SubscribeOnDispatcher<TSource>(System.IObservable<TSource>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context...` with the code above. My first adventure in to Reactive so....

Comment: @cek: Apologies, my code update was missing the brackets for the SubscribeOnDispatcher() call. I've updated the original answer again.

Comment: That did it. All these .net syntaxes are hard to keep up with. Lambdas, reactive LINQ, etc...  When do you use commas, semi-colons, line breaks, brackets, blah, blah, blah. Thanks.

Comment: Recently I just use your method again, but it would raise an exception ("Invalid cross-thread access.") if I tried to update an UI element in it. So SubscribeOnDispatcher() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think replacing `.SubscribeOnDispatcher()` with `.ObserveOnDisaptcher()' or `.ObserveOn(Deployment.Current.Dispatcher())` should work.